# Sending and proceeding POST request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have very simple node.js server which has

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.post('/savearticles', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.body);
});
```

and not much more difficult javascript code

```
    var xmlHTTP = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            alert(xmlHTTP.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlHTTP.open('POST', '/savearticles', true);
    xmlHTTP.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    xmlHTTP.send('postparameter');
```

It returns undefined (checked by returning *(typeof res.body)*).  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you log out req as well as typeof req?

Comment: @tocoolforscool, heres log of req https://pastebin.com/8wknLipk
typeof req is object

Comment: @tocoolforscool, I've put *alert* inside *if* and it works, its just empty.

Comment: try alerting something else?  it seems to me that everything is working but your res is possibly empty which wouldnt make much sense if everything is working right, unless youre testing/outputting the wrong thing.  play around with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware. Install it and your code should work correctly.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/savearticles', (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.body)
})
```

Comment: And in addition to this answer it still didn't want to receive *string* parameter, but accepted *JSON.stringify(myObject)* as parameter and just *myObject* aswell.